# A error from RastertoNumpyArray: <except str() failed>

Tags: arcpy, raster, numpy

I need to do some calculation between two Raster, and I first find the arcpy.plus_3d etc., but I find that if I can use Numpy to do this calculation, it would be more simple.

I get stuck in the first step, the only command I type in is:

**

```
import arcpy,numpy
arr1=arcpy.RastertoNumpyArray("C:/test.tif")
```

**

```
**
error message:

_RasterToNumPyArray(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError:<exception str() failed>

**
```

and the error is shown again and again:

since I had built the pyramids before, I think it's not its falut.

I find that all the others can use this freely, but I can not solve this problem, I use Arcgis 10.4 and the version from arcgis is 2.7.13, maybe I miss some package to install?

Comment: the error message is:    return _RasterToNumPyArray(*args, **kwargs)      RuntimeError: <exception str() failed>

Comment: Use r=arcpy.Raster(tifname) first and convert r to array.

Comment: It's quite akward that since I delete the files and generate them , this method doesn't work again...It seems that the real way to solve it is not found yet.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem finally.

In such a simply code, the only error will occur is MemoryError, no matter what error information it appears.

So I clip my tif files first in order to make them small enough to be load into the Numpy.

That's my solution.

Here's an example:

```
#The origin code:

arr=arcpy.RastertoNumpyArray("C:/test1.tif")
arr+=arr
arrraster=arcpy.NumpyArrayToRaster(arr)
arrraster.save("C:/test2.tif")
myraster=arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask("C:/test2.tif",file)
myraster.save("C:/test3.tif")

#Then I change it to the following one:

myraster=arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask("C:/test1.tif",file)
myraster.save("C:/test2.tif")
arr=arcpy.RastertoNumpyArray("C:/test2.tif")
arr+=arr
arrraster=arcpy.NumpyArrayToRaster(arr)
arrraster.save("C:/test3.tif")
```

In the origin code, my tif file is nearly 10M a file, it does a quite complex computation unlike the below, so it will cause the MemoryError, no matter what it appears. In the Changed code, I clip my file first, and is nearly 10k-100k a file, which makes it possible to be load into the numpy.